# How to insert checkbox value in phpmyadmin in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have created an application in which I am sending data to phpmyadmin database from flutter, but I dont know how to send checkbox values.
I have used online hosting and sending data from JSON.
I dont know how to get value of selected checkboxes

```
CheckboxListTile(title: const Text('Scrub Sinks'),
   value: _user.tasks[User.ScrubSinks],
   onChanged: (val) {
      setState(()=> _user .tasks[User.ScrubSinks]=val);
   }

   ,
),
CheckboxListTile(title: const Text('Trash Emptied'),
   value: _user.tasks[User.trashemptied],
   onChanged: (val) {
      setState(()=> _user .tasks[User.trashemptied]=val);
   }

   ,
),
Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
   child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
         final form=_formkey.currentState;

         if(form.validate()) {
            form.save();
            _user.save();

            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                     return days();
                  }

               ));
         }
      }

      ,
      child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(color: Theme .of(context) .primaryColor,
         ),
      ),
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears that you are assigning the boolean values of checkboxes to the properties of _user.tasks Map. The routine which is responsible for transmitting that info (presumably *_user.save()*) to the server should take care of the JSON encoding of those boolean values. Typically it is done with the help of json.encode(..) call from dart:convert package.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json